# A fair coin is flipped 2k times. What is the probability that it comes up tails more often than it comes up heads?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm studying for a probability exam and came across this question. I watched the video solution to it but I don't really understand it. I was hoping someone could explain this problem to me. Are there different ways to go about this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Hint**:

The probability that an equal number of tails and heads appear is $\large{{2k \choose k} \frac{1}{2^{2k}}}$

The two remaining outcomes (that there are more heads than tails or more tails than heads) are equally likely.

Comment: It seems likely that the "2k" in the question refers to a general even number $2k$ rather than "2000".

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Well, just replace $000$ with $k$, then. ;-)

Comment: When the question was first posted, I believe OP used "a coin is flipped 2000 times." Also, holy cow, why did this question / my answer get so much attention? Wouldn't think that this answer would be my highest rated non-CW answer..

Answer (score 13):

Hint:

1. Fair coin $\implies$ Probability of tails occurring more $=$ probability of heads occurring more $= p$, say.
2. Probability of exactly equal number of heads and tails $=1-2p$.  Can you find this one?

Comment: If the probability of tails occurring more = probability of heads occurring more = p then p = 0. The coin is fair therefore neither head or tails has a probability of occurring more than the other.

Comment: If the probability of heads + probability of tails = 1 - 2p where p = 0 and probability of heads and tails are equal, probability of heads = 1/2 and probability of tails = 1/2

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins What on Earth are you talking about?

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins  In any particular set of $2k$ throws with a fair coin, there are three mutually exclusive and collectively exhaustive possibilities - (1) exactly $k$ heads (and tails) occur (2) more than $k$ heads occur or (3) less than $k$ heads occur.  Why do you think possibilities (2) or (3) have zero probability?

Comment: My understanding of a fair coin is that the probability of a head appearing is precisely the same as a tail appearing. Am I wrong?

Comment: My understanding is that in order for the probability to be accurate: In 10 throws, 5 will have to be heads and 5 will have to be tails. Therefore, there will never be more heads thrown than tails nor vice-versa. The only way for there to be more heads than tails is if the coin is thrown an odd number of times as far as I can see, but does this affect probability? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins Think of only one throw.  What happens?  Does this contradict the probability of equal heads and tails?  You may need to brush up on reading or have a chat with someone on this, not much point discussing here...

Comment: Does this mean that you need to take into account the probability of tossing a coin an even or odd number of times? The question states 2k times and this is an even number. Even probability = 1 and odd probability = 0. I think I'm doing by good by discussing the topic, because I can't be far off the answer even if I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins: that the coin is fair just means that both sides have an equal chance *every single throw*. That doesn't mean that 10 throws will always result in 5/5 at all. Try it out for yourself.

Comment: Due to my understanding of a fair coin, the coin wouldn't be deemed fair unless out of an even number of throws, the results are equal so the results are in fact always 5/5. If the number of heads are different to the number of tails then I would consider the coin as either 'might be fair' or 'unfair' and therefore discount the results due to the question stating that a fair coin be used.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins That understanding is incorrect. A fair coin merely has equal probability of getting heads or tails, in any toss, as mentioned above.  It does not have memory (it does not remember we had 4 heads so far and five tails, so the next one I should give heads).  The "fair coin" as you have described can only produce one of two sequences (HTHTHTHTHT..) or (THTHTHTHT...) - as we can start counting tosses from any point - so really is not random at all except perhaps for the very first toss in its entire life.

Comment: @Knickerless-Noggins The probability that a fair coin produces as many heads than tails in $2n$ throws actually **goes to zero** when $n\to\infty$. Already when $n=5$ ($10$ throws), this probability is less than $25\%$.

Comment: Interesting. How do you calculate the probability on a Heads being thrown then? Is it accumulative?